# How to count the number of occurrences of the sequence in a string?

Tags: c, string

Write a C program to count the number of occurrences of the sequence ‘abc’ in an input string. However, there can be any letters between (a and b) or (b and c).

Example of the output:

```
Enter a string: ann bmm cmm 
Count is: 1
```

Example of the output:

```
Enter a string: ann bmm cmm ckc 
Count is: 3
```

Comment: @Jess Brown  How did you get 3 in the second example?

Comment: If the input was: `pax byb zic abbc`, what should the output be?  8?

Comment: *"However, there can be any letters between (a and b) or (b and c)."* Huh? There can be *No* letters between (a and b) or (b and c). It is unclear what you are asking. How are you defining *sequence*? If at least *one* of each, but less than *two* of each occurs, the answer is `1`? If that is the case, your second example does not add up to `3`?

Answer (score 1):

Let `a[k]` be equal to the number of `'a'` with indices `i<=k`.
Let `c[k]` be equal to the number of `'c'` with indices `i>=k`.
Then for every `k: s[k] == 'b'` we have `a[k]*c[k]` solutions.

This is a possible implementation (the algorithm can be simplified, for instance, only one array is needed):

```
char* s = "pax byb zic abbc";
int n = strlen(s);
int a[n], c[n];
a[0] = (s[0] == 'a') ? 1 : 0;
for (int k = 1; k < n; ++k)
    a[k] = a[k - 1] + ((s[k] == 'a') ? 1 : 0);
c[n - 1] = (s[n - 1] == 'c') ? 1 : 0;
for (int k = n - 2; k >= 0; --k)
    c[k] = c[k + 1] + ((s[k] == 'c') ? 1 : 0);
int r = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    if (s[k] == 'b')
        r += a[k] * c[k];
printf("%d\n", r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this problem just cry out for recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int occurrences(const char *pattern, const char *string) {
    int sum = 0;

    size_t p_length = strlen(pattern);

    if (p_length > 0) {

        size_t s_length = strlen(string);

        for (int i = 0; i < s_length; i++) {

            if (pattern[0] == string[i]) {
                sum += (p_length == 1) ? 1 : occurrences(pattern + 1, string + i + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", occurrences(argv[1], argv[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLES**

```
> ./a.out "abc" "ann bmm cmm"
1
> ./a.out "abc" "ann bmm cmm ckc"
3
> ./a.out "abc" "pax byb zic abbc"
8
>
```

Comment: It seems to have `O(N^3)` complexity instead of possible `O(N)`. (But on the other hand, it is not limited to 3-letter patterns.)